# Java GUI/Swing, stopping the thread, passing integers between classes

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm trying to make a simulation of a roulette game using GUI/Swing for my upcoming exam. I have two classes, one is called GUI and is actually the code used for the components, such as JFrame, JOptionPane, JButtons etc. The other one extends Thread and is supposed to show random numbers on a small JLabel, and the run method goes something like this:

```
public void run() {
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        k = (new Random().nextInt(37));
        label.setText(k + " ");
        label.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 56));
        label.setForeground(Color.yellow);
        try {
            sleep(50);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }       
}
```

And in the GUI class I just want to TAKE the number from the last iteration of the above loop, and then pass it to a new int, which I'm going to use later in the GUI class.
Any ideas?

Comment: Use a Swing Timer as @Braj recommends (1+ to his answer). Also as an aside, you almost never want to extend the Thread class. If you needed to use basic Threads and absolutely couldn't use a Swing Timer or a SwingWorker, then you'd want your class to implement Runnable, not extend Thread.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) instead of `Thread.sleep` that sometime hangs the whole swing application.

Please have a look at [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

```
Timer timer = new Timer(50, new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {            
        //next call from here
    }
});
timer.setRepeats(false);
timer.start();
```

---

> I just want to TAKE the number from the last iteration of the above loop, and then pass it to a new int, which I'm going to use later in the GUI class.

Just create a method (setter) in another class that accepts int and call it from this class for last call.

---

Sample code:

```
private int counter = 0;
private Timer timer;
...

final JLabel label = new JLabel();
label.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 56));
label.setForeground(Color.yellow);
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

        timer = new Timer(50, new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (counter++ < 50) {
                    int k = (new Random().nextInt(37));
                    label.setText(k + " ");
                } else {
                    timer.stop();
                    label.setText("next call");
                }

            }
        });
        timer.setRepeats(true);
        timer.start();
    }
});

thread.start();
```

snapshot:

[image]